# TCL I want to read fail2ban new logs and print them to some channel

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I want to read all new lines from fail2ban logs when filesize or lines count changed.
I want to print only new lines in fail2ban logs to specified channel.

I try:

```
bind time - * checklogs
set kanal "#logzzz"
set logf2b "/var/log/fail2ban.log"

proc linecount {file} {
        set i 0
        set fid [open $file r]
        while {[gets $fid line] > -1} {incr i}
        close $fid
        return $i
}

set oldlines [linecount $logf2b]
set filesize [file size $logf2b]

proc checklogs {min hour day mon year} {
    global kanal oldlines logf2b filesize
    if {[file size $logf2b] != $filesize} {
        set newfile [open $logf2b "r"]
        while {1} {
            set line [gets $newfile $oldlines]
            if {[eof $newfile]} {
                close $newfile
                break
            }
            putserv "PRIVMSG $kanal :Fail2Ban $line"
        }
    } else { putserv "PRIVMSG $kanal :No new fail2ban logs!" }
}
```

But doesnt work :/

Any solutions or explanations how to make?

Comment: "doesn't work" is useless as a problem report. What *does* happen?

Comment: This looks very suspicious: `set line [gets $newfile $oldlines]`